# xcode build archive shows shell script invocation error

Tags: ios, xcode

alamofire framework have error shows unrecognized arguments[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMwqn.png)

[image]

Comment: you only install alamofire pod?

Comment: using carthage i have installed alamofire

Comment: Untill now I haven't used carthrage but there is a .sh file which you have to installed in your pc. Please search through like Install shell file into terminal

Comment: Did you able to solve this?